# Draw Rectangle with HTML5 canvas like painting program in windows

Tags: html, canvas

I'm writing a painting application with canvas in HTML5.
I've finished my pencil painting with touching and drawing.
And now i'm trying to make a rectangle. For all the topic i've read, i will have to store all of my finished shape in an array, but if i do that, i will also have to store all the point with normal drawing so that i could draw a rectangle like windows painting.
Please give me another solution to draw rectangle like windows, which old rectangle will be dissappeared and new one will replace before i make a "mouse up".
thanks in advance :)

Comment: i've tried storing all of my data into an array, but i'm so worried if my program will have to store so much data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You will either need to save the previous drawings or use 2 canvases.**

*If you want to save the previous drawings...*

In mousedown:

- Save the mouse position (startX/startY).
- Set a flag indicating that a drag has started (isDown=true)

In mousemove:

- if isDown==false, don't do anything (return)
- otherwise, clear the canvas
- redraw all your previous drawings (from your saved points array, etc)
- draw the current rect from the start to mouse position -- context.strokeRect(startX,startY,mouseX-startX,mouseY-startY)

In mouseup:

- clear the drag flag (isDown=false)

*If you want to use 2 canvases...*

As an alternative to storing every previous drawing, you can use 2 canvases.  One canvas is used to draw the current rectangle and a second canvas to keep all the previously draw items Here's an example using 2 canvases so you don't have to store previous drawings: jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/V9J5J/